# Stop messages from going to /var/log/debug

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

I have a daemon running, milter-regex that is absolutely polluting my /var/log/debug file.  After some digging around I thought by adding the "daemon.err;daemon.notice /var/log/milter-regex" that that would stop the milter-regex stuff from going into /var/log/debug.  But that didn't work.  What am I missing?

My  /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf file:

```
#
# Some "catch-all" log files.
#
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        cron,daemon.none;\
        mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages

daemon.err;daemon.notice /var/log/milter-regex

#
# NOTE: adjust the list below, or you'll go crazy if you have a reasonably
#      busy site..
#
daemon.*;mail.*;\
        news.err;\
        *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for extra safety, add daemon.none to avoid daemon messages going to debug

```
*.=debug;\
        auth,authpriv.none;\
        news.none;mail.none;\
        daemon.none     -/var/log/debug
```

That'll also stop any other daemon messages getting to your debug log though.

Also I don't think you want to send all `daemon.err` and `daemon.notice` to a milter-regex explicit file.

If I were you I would try to look at milter-regex to either send messsages through `mail.*` (it's related to mail after all) or just to write itself to a log file

Comment: Alternatively, configure milter-regex not to send `debug` level log messages...

Comment: voretaq7 - do you know how to configure it not to send debug messages?  I've been through the manual @ http://linux.die.net/man/8/milter-regex, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1):

In the file that starts the `milter-regex` daemon you can set the type of logging with the parameter `-l n`,
`n` being the level: `5` for Notice, `6` for Informational, or `7` for Debug.

In my case (Debian Linux), this is done in `/etc/init.d/milter-regex`.